How to have chapters and sections when compiling with xcomment?
I have a structured file with chapters, sections, and lots of theorems etc. and want to extract only exercises to a separate file.
Package xcomment and a simple
\xcomment{exercises}
basically does the job. However, exercises end up being numerated as 0.n (since in the original file I want them numerated by chapters).
What I'd like to have as output is a structured document with chapters and sections, but with exercises as the only content.
Edit: Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,notitlepage,a4paper]{book}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter]
\usepackage{xcomment}
\xcomment{exercise}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{chap}
\section{sect}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem, not to be included in the file.
\end{theorem}

Random text
\begin{exercise}
This should be included
\end{exercise}

\end{document}


Welcome! I’m not sure that your strategy is the best. Anyway, a small example to play with is needed.

Thank you! I edited the question with a mwe.
